# TYPO3/Extbase/flashmessages: How to localize and/or individualize system flash messages?

Tags: typo3, extbase

When a new object in my extbase extension is created via Extbase/Fluid (fluid f:form, newAction -> createAction) and a validation error occurs, then a flash message is displayed:

`An error occurred while trying to call MyVendor\MyExtension\Controller\MyObjectController->createAction()`

How can I influence the content of this message? And how can I localize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Extbase controller contains an `errorAction()`, which is called exactly in such a case. You can find it's original definition in `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController` class.

You can override this action in your own controller or override only part of it - methods, that construct a FlashMessage: `addErrorFlashMessage()` or `getErrorFlashMessage()`.

*Side note*: If you just see this error message, but not the contents of a form, which creates your object, and no validation errors are available via `<f:form.validationResults>` VH, it means, that something went wrong in your MVC process. Because as you can see from `errorAction()` it forwards to the previous request and restores it.